# Passing an array to a JS script

Tags: javascript

so what I am trying to do is pass a list to an included js file:

```
script src="{% static 'js/on-enter.js' %}" type="text/javascript" newItemName=["Value","Value2"]</script>
```

My js file retrieves the value as the following:

```
newItemName = document.currentScript.getAttribute('newItemName');
```

The problem I face is that the var gets read as a string while I want it to be an array, how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: HTML attributes *are* strings. `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options for you:

### Using an attribute

If you want to use an attribute as you have in the question, in the HTML, the attribute value should be in quotes (since your value includes quotes as text; [more in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2)); since the content of an attribute is HTML text, you'll need to ensure it's properly marked up (using whatever function your server-side code lets you use; **don't** do it manually). The result would be:

```
newItemName="[&quot;Value&quot;,&quot;Value2&quot;]"
```

When you get that from `getAttribute`, parse it using `JSON.parse`:

```
newItemName = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.getAttribute("newItemName"));
```

`newItemName` will be an array of strings.

### Using the content of the script tag

When a `script` tag has a `src` attribute, the script tag's *contents* are ignored by the browser; the contents are [script documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts). So you could put your JSON there:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/on-enter.js' %}" type="text/javascript">
["Value","Value2"]
</script>
```

Then

```
newItemName = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.textContent);
```

Or perhaps:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/on-enter.js' %}" type="text/javascript">
{"newItemName": ["Value","Value2"]}
</script>
```

and

```
info = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.textContent);
// Use `info.newItemName` and others here...
```

if you have other information you want to include.

---

Side note: `newItemName` isn't a valid attribute for `script` tags. If you want to embed arbitrary data on an element, use [`data-*` attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes), e.g.:

```
data-new-item-name="[&quot;Value&quot;,&quot;Value2&quot;]"
```

In addition to making the HTML valid, in modern browsers, that would let you access it via [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset):

```
newItemName = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.dataset.newItemName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
<script newItemNames="Value1,Value2"></script>
```

And get the array in js file like that:

```
const newItemNames = document.currentScript.getAttribute('newItemNames').split(',');
```

I guess it's the easiest way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
newItemName = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.getAttribute('newItemName'));
```

Comment: Thanks. That is perfect